# Sort object based on another object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following array generated from HTML structure:

```
const sort = [{ section_id: 'b', children: ['2'] }, { section_id: 'a', children: ['1', '3'] }]
```

each object in this array represents a section, where children is an array of content ids belonging to that section.

There is also a product object:

```
const product = {
            id: 'asd',
            title: 'product title',
            sections: [
                { id: 'a', title: 'section with id a', contents: [{ id: '1' }] },
                { id: 'b', title: 'section with id b', contents: [{ id: '2' }, { id: '3' }] }
            ]
}
```

I would like to "re-create" product object based on data coming from sort, so the result in this example would be like so:

```
const sortedProduct = {
            id: 'asd',
            title: 'product title',
            sections: [
                { id: 'b', title: 'section with id b', contents: [{ id: '2' }] },
                { id: 'a', title: 'section with id a', contents: [{ id: '1' }, { id: '3' }] }
            ]
}
```

I have wrote following function to accomplish just that but first section contains all contents in correct order, rest is just repeat of first one. Please point me to what i'm doing wrong.

```
const SrtProduct = () => {
    const sort = serializeSections() // returns array as in example
    let sortedProduct = {}
    sortedProduct.sections = []
    const emptySection = {
        _id: '',
        contents: [],
        title: ''
    }
    Object.keys($productStore).forEach(key => {
        if(key !== 'sections') sortedProduct[key] = product[key]
    })

    sort.forEach((section, index) => {
        sortedProduct.sections[index] = emptySection
        let pozycja = getIndex(product.sections, section.id)
        Object.keys(product.sections[index]).forEach(key => {
            if(key !== 'contents') sortedProduct.sections[index][key] = product.sections[pozycja][key]
        })

        if(section.children.length > 0) section.children.forEach((content_id, ind) => {
            let poz = getContentIndex(product.sections, content_id)
            let tmp = sortedProduct.sections[index]
            tmp.contents.push(product.sections[poz[0]].contents[poz[1]])
            sortedProduct.sections[index] = tmp
        })
    })

    return sortedProduct
}
```

Above code returns:

```
...
sections: [
                { id: 'a', title: 'section with id a', contents: [{id: '2'}, {id: '1'}, {id: '3'}] },
                { id: 'b', title: 'section with id b', contents: [{id: '2'}, {id: '1'}, {id: '3'}] }
            ]
```

Helper functions getIndex and getContentIndex both work correctly.

**getIndex** returns position in array where section with given id is found. ex. getIndex(product.sections, 'b') would return 1

**getContentIndex** ex. getContentIndex(product.sections, '2') would return [1,0] (section position 1, content position 0)

**Input:** *product*, *sort*

**Output** *sortedProduct* which is *product* with rearranged sections and contents according to information from *sort*

Comment: please specify what should be the input and output the code is make confusing , what is a `$productStore` , what is `getIndex` and `getContentIndex `?

Comment: I have edited question. Hope this makes it clear.
$productStore is a svelte store, i have corrected question to refer only variables that are used in question.

I have created REPL with problem replicated: https://svelte.dev/repl/c7bf44867a7b48879cfd5bcfe3b197bf?version=3.20.1

you can drag and drop sections and elements, pressing button gives result of SrtProduct function

Comment: I have updated my answer please check it ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some mistakes in your code, `section.id` will be undefined because you are looping over `sort` it only have `section_id` no `id`, any way I rewritten your code to get the 
 expected out put .

```
const SrtProduct = () => {
    const sort = [{ section_id: 'b', children: ['2'] }, { section_id: 'a', children: ['1', '3'] }]; // returns array as in example
    const $productStore ={
            id: 'asd',
            title: 'product title',
            sections: [
                { id: 'a', title: 'section with id a', contents: [{ id: '1' }] },
                { id: 'b', title: 'section with id b', contents: [{ id: '2' }, { id: '3' }] }
            ]
};
    let sortedProduct = Object.assign({}, $productStore);
    sortedProduct.sections=[];
    // const emptySection = {
    //     _id: '',
    //     contents: [],
    //     title: ''
    // }

    sort.forEach((section, index) => {
        // sortedProduct.sections[index] = emptySection
        let product_sections_index = $productStore.sections.findIndex(x => x.id ===section.section_id);
        sortedProduct.sections[index] = $productStore.sections[product_sections_index]

        // Object.keys(product.sections[index]).forEach(key => {
        //     if(key !== 'contents') sortedProduct.sections[index][key] = product.sections[pozycja][key]
        // })
        sortedProduct.sections[index].contents = [];
        section.children.forEach((value,index2) => {
            sortedProduct.sections[index].contents[index2] = {id: value};
        })
        // if(section.children.length > 0) section.children.forEach((content_id, ind) => {
        //     let poz = getContentIndex(product.sections, content_id)
        //     let tmp = sortedProduct.sections[index]
        //     tmp.contents.push(product.sections[poz[0]].contents[poz[1]])
        //     sortedProduct.sections[index] = tmp
        // })
    })

    return sortedProduct
};
```

[you can see/run the code here](https://codepen.io/prajin/pen/GRJejJO?editors=0012//)